# How does sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask works?

Tags: sql-server, function, bit-manipulation

As stated above, how does sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask works in SQL Server? Can you provide me an example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents the spot in a binary number that is flipped on, so since 111  in binary is '7' (the 1st, second, and third bits are on). Then lets use the hexadecimal number 0x7 for the first argument in this  function and check the 1 bit

(I will use convert() to varbinary here just to make it evident that this is a representation of a binary number, you dont need the convert() function)

```
       select sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask(convert(VARBINARY, 0x7),1)
```

This returns something <> 0 (so far i have only seen the return value be 2^(7+n) with the second argument of the sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask function being n). Another example would be if we gave hex number 0xa, which equals 1010 in binary, then the 4th bit and 2nd bit is flipped on (has ones).  so the funcation calls

```
     if   (sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask(convert(VARBINARY, 0xa),2)<> 0)
        if   (sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask(convert(VARBINARY, 0xa),4) <> 0)
           select 'sup son'
```

Will return 'sup son'. Just selecting the value from say

```
     select sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask(convert(VARBINARY, 0xa),4)
```

Will return a value 2^(7+n) with n being 4 so 2^11 which is 2048

Comment: Many thanks! One additional question (just being curious): Why does SELECT sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask(convert(VARBINARY(2), 0xaa),8) returns -32768 instead of 32768?

Comment: @guillegr123 -one reason is that the function actually works in smaller data sizes than `int`, and especially, it's return line is `convert( smallint, @oldword ) & convert( smallint, @mask )`. [`smallint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187745.aspx) has a range of -32768 to 32767.

Comment: This is used with COLUMNS_UPDATED() often http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Comment: You really should not be using `> 0` but `<> 0` instead. Yes it works for this specific example because you are only checking the 2nd and 4th bit. If you are checking the 8th, the 24th, the 40th (and so on) bit the function will return a negative. It is better practice to just always use `<> 0`, especially online at sites where people may copy your code without understanding what you are doing.